# Is there an R function that can Create a URL to open a PDF file at a specific page?

Tags: r, pdf, url, hyperlink

In Adobe you can do create a URL link to send to a page within the PDF:

https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html

I am in the process of creating a training manual for work, and within this I have a flow chart of actions. Within some of these actions I would like links to other pages within the manual to better outline the process. Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Are you using Rmarkdown? Maybe use `[Google](www.google.com)` ? See [here](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/rmarkdown-cheatsheet.pdf) for more info.

Comment: How are you creating your PDF? And you're trying to do internal links, which isn't what that adobe.com page is talking about is it? That's about creating HTML that links to a separate PDF to open it in Acrobat at page X?

Comment: Thanks guys. What I am trying to do is to create an interactive flow chart as part of a wider PDF training manual. I want to be able to click on aspects of the flowchart and it do direct you to a certain page within the PDF - is this possible? All links will be internal.

Comment: I'll be creating this in markdown